# Finding substring in Formula in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I need to check for the existance of a substring in a formula and remove it. 
Can someone please suggest a work-around for that. 
Currently I'm having a formula that joins the user input into comma seperated string. My requirment is to check if this formula contains "All" and if so remove it.

Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Replace function.

Code:

```
Replace (inputString, findString, replaceString)
```

Example

```
Replace ({@YourJoinedCommaDelimitedFormula}, 'All', '')
```

The above will replace the word 'All' with a blank string so it will remove it from the list.